# Trouble with assigning values to struct pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I'm constructing a linked list dictionary with a  structure, with each node in the list defined as the following:

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node
{                                                               
      int key;
      char value[ARRAY_MAX];
      node *next;
};
```

Where I'm running into problems is when I'm assigning values to key or value within my insert and makedict functions. I received the following errors in assignment:

```
node* insert(node* start, char* vinput, int kinput) {
    node* temp = start;
    while((temp->next->key < kinput) && temp->next!=NULL) {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp->key==kinput) {
        temp->key = kinput;
        return temp;
    } else {
        node* inputnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        inputnode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = inputnode;
        inputnode->key = kinput;   /*error: incompatible types in assignment*/
        inputnode->value = vinput;
        return inputnode;
}
```

and:

```
node* makedict(char* vinput, int kinput) {
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->value = vinput;
    temp->key = kinput; /*error: incompatible types in assignment*/
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

I know I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious, but I've been reading this code over and over to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From a quick glance, `if(temp->key==kinput)` why are you assigning `temp->key = kinput;` again? :\

Comment: Oh you're right, a bit of redundant code! I think I may have left it there in an abandoned attempt to store repeated key inputs. Good pickup :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the line

```
inputnode->value = vinput;
```

is what the compiler is complaining about. Try

```
strcpy(inputnode->value, vinput);
```

Or, better yet, make the 'value' field a char * and do

```
inputnode->value = strdup(vinput)
```

Comment: `strdup` is not standard C, is it?

Comment: I'll most likely stick to the strcpy, otherwise I'd have to define strdup (I don't think it's ANSI C)

Comment: You probably have strdup. It's in #include <string.h>. Try "man strdup".